# My app won't start running because it can't find the class MainActivity

Tags: android, flutter

I have implemented this up and finished it and as a final touch I wanted to add a splash screen using the [native_splash_screen](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash) package.

My app stopped working on Android 12, so I decided to remove it, but then my app stopped working on other androids as well.

I just face this error whenever I run it. I created a new project and migrated the lib folder along with the other necessary files to run the app, but I still face the same error.

Here is how my debug console looks like:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Parameter format not correct -
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
E/AndroidRuntime(16701): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(16701): Process: net.bookdoor.book_door, PID: 16701
E/AndroidRuntime(16701): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{net.bookdoor.book_door/com.example.application.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.application.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~PZh1v9AiUGsjRdmpGp6NnQ==/net.bookdoor.book_door-2TdjEBVdRLtbluVhxIV8qg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~PZh1v9AiUGsjRdmpGp6NnQ==/net.bookdoor.book_door-2TdjEBVdRLtbluVhxIV8qg==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~PZh1v9AiUGsjRdmpGp6NnQ==/net.bookdoor.book_door-2TdjEBVdRLtbluVhxIV8qg==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(16701):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3551)
E/AndroidRuntime(16701):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
E/AndroidRuntime(16701):    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
E/AndroidRuntime(16701):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(16701):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(16701):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
E/AndroidRuntime(16701):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(16701):    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
E/AndroidRuntime(16701):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/AndroidRuntime(16701):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
E/AndroidRuntime(16701):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(16701):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
E/AndroidRuntime(16701):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
E/AndroidRuntime(16701): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.application.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~PZh1v9AiUGsjRdmpGp6NnQ==/net.bookdoor.book_door-2TdjEBVdRLtbluVhxIV8qg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~PZh1v9AiUGsjRdmpGp6NnQ==/net.bookdoor.book_door-2TdjEBVdRLtbluVhxIV8qg==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~PZh1v9AiUGsjRdmpGp6NnQ==/net.bookdoor.book_door-2TdjEBVdRLtbluVhxIV8qg==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(16701):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
E/AndroidRuntime(16701):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime(16701):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime(16701):    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(16701):    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
E/AndroidRuntime(16701):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1339)
E/AndroidRuntime(16701):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3538)
E/AndroidRuntime(16701):    ... 12 more
Exited (1)
```

Comment: It can't find MainActivity.  Either you renamed the class and forgot to update the manifest, you forgot to put the Activity in the manifest at all, or you used proguard/R8/other to rename it and confused the system